# Route change does not work in promise callback function

Tags: angularjs, routes

I have a login screen that takes a username and password and authenticates them against a web service. If the web service returns "true" indicating that the user is authenticated, I want to redirect the user to the logged-in home page. Here is the code for this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app');
app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, UserService) {
    $scope.authUser = function () {
        UserService.AuthenticateUser($scope.Username, $scope.Password)
            .then(function (result) {
                // Check contents of HTTP response for "true".
                if (result.data == "true") {
                    // Web service returned "true" indicated user is authenticated; therefore, redirect to logged-in home page.
                    $location.path("/home");
                } else {
                    // Web service returned "false" indicating user is not authenticated.
                    alert("Authentication failed.");
                }
            })
            .catch(function () {
                alert("Attempt to authenticate user failed.");
            });
    };
});
app.factory('UserService', function ($http) {
    return {
        AuthenticateUser: function (username, password) {
            var url = "https://<redacted>/";
            var request = {
                "Username": username,
                "Password": password
            };
            return $http.post(url + 'auth', request);
        }
    };
});
```

My problem is with the following line:

```js
$location.path("/home");
```

The web service is working fine, the line is hit in the debugger, but the route change does not occur. No errors appear in the console.

Does this have something to do with the digest lifecycle? With how promises work? Routing works fine elsewhere in the application, it is just when I attempt to use it after an $http call that it fails to work. Is this even the right pattern in angular for changing views?

Routing:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
    });
$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
```

Comment: are you using angular  ui-router ? or  default angularjs routing module ?

Comment: Good question...I am using the default router. The one from angular named angular-route.js. I'm fairly new to angular, so in over my head a bit.

Comment: your browser url changes ? or either?

Comment: The browser url flickers but does not change. It starts at #/login, flickers, and remains at #/login.

Comment: do you have a rule for matching "/home"? can you paste your router code.

Comment: SWAG, try putting a `#` in front of url segment `$location.path("#/home");`

Comment: Michael Coleman, nice idea, but that results in "#/%23/home" in the browser, and the route does not change.

Comment: try  $location.path('/home').replace(); it will do with force full manner :-)

Comment: well it tells you `$location` is working. The code youve posted looks good to me. did you add `ng-route` as a dependency when you created your angular app?

Comment: @MichaelColeman, `ngRoute` is injected and is working fine elsewhere. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @levi, I'm taking a look at your answer right now. My initial test resulted in the "digest already in progress" error. I am going to try your suggestion to use angular-ui-router, because I seem to be running into an obscure issue based on the combination of versions of angular libraries and code that I have implemented. I'm either missing something simple or not getting enough sleep.

Comment: By the way I have html5mode set to false because I'm using this in Cordova in a web-server-less scenario, though the current testing I'm doing at the moment is in Chrome.

Comment: I'm doing the same thing you are in my app.  My redirect looks like: `$location.path("/requests");` and it just works.  I'm not having to call $scope.apply or anything else.  What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: If you navigate directly to that route does it work?  http://whatever/url#/home   And  also, are you including ngRoute in your app declaration?  angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])

Comment: Okay, my apologies everyone. The code I posted is actually working as is, but the /home page had some code in it that was expecting an auth token that I had not been setting in my login page. The purpose of this is to handle back-buttons; if the auth token is not present, any attempts to load a view get rejected. Anyway, that's what I get for working on little sleep. Thanks for the help everyone. Levi, since you answered, do you want to update your answer reflecting what I just said? I think this scenario, and its seeming validity as a pattern, may be useful to keep around.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `$scope.$apply()` after change your url.

```
$location.path("/home");
$scope.$apply()
```

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries).

But, I recommend you, enable `html5mode` and use angular `ui-router`.

**EDIT**

If you get "digest already in progress", wrap up your `$location.path` into `$timeout`, remember to inject it first.

```
$timeout(function() {
  $location.path("/home");
})
```

Then you url change will run safaly on the next digest cycle. .

Comment: IF we use ui-router, do we have to wrap the $location call in a $scope.$apply()?

Comment: @Rohan if you are calling $location inside a third party lib function, yes.